# How to run a code in render repeatedly? (libgdx)

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Im stuck at the idea of running this code:

```
package com.mygdx.Papermadness;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Papermadness extends InputAdapter implements ApplicationListener {

SpriteBatch huisBatch;
Texture huisTexture;
SpriteBatch batch;
Sprite sprite;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
Sprite huisSprite;  
Texture spriteTexture;  
float scrollTimer = 0.0f;
float huisVelocity = 200f;  
float huisY = 1900;
float huisX = 0;
float huisY1 = 1900;
float huisX1 = 903;
private Sprite huis;
private ArrayList<Sprite> huisArray = new ArrayList<Sprite>();

Rectangle bounds;
Player player;
Paper paper;
ShapeRenderer sr;

@Override
public void create() {

player = new Player(new Vector2(50, 100), new Vector2(100, 100));   
paper = new Paper(new        Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY()), new Vector2(50, 50));
sr = new ShapeRenderer();
spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
huisBatch = new SpriteBatch();
huisTexture = new Texture("huis.png");
huisSprite = new Sprite(huisTexture);
spriteTexture = new Texture("b2.png");
spriteTexture.setWrap(TextureWrap.Repeat, TextureWrap.Repeat);
sprite = new Sprite(spriteTexture);
sprite.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
batch = new SpriteBatch();

}

@Override
public void render() {

  Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

scrollTimer += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
if (scrollTimer > 2f)
    scrollTimer = 0.0f;

sprite.setV(scrollTimer + 2);
sprite.setV2(scrollTimer);

player.update();
paper.update();

spriteBatch.begin();
sprite.draw(spriteBatch);
spriteBatch.end();



 for (int i = 0; i < huisArray.size(); i++) {
        huisArray.get(i).setY(huisArray.get(i).getY() - huisVelocity * delta);

             if (huisArray.get(i).getY() <= 200) {
            huisArray.remove(huisArray.get(i));
        } 
    }

 if (huisArray.get(0).getY() < 1200) {
        addNewHuis();
    }

huisBatch.begin();


  for (int i = 0; i < huisArray.size(); i++) {
        huisBatch.draw(huisArray.get(i), huisArray.get(i).getX(), huisArray.get(i).getY());
    }


huisY -= huisVelocity * delta;
huisY1 -= huisVelocity * delta;

batch.begin();  
player.draw(batch);
paper.draw(batch);  
batch.end();

sr.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
sr.setColor(Color.BLUE);

sr.setColor(Color.RED);

sr.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
sr.rect(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - Gdx.input.getY(), paper.getSize().x,
    paper.getSize().y);
sr.end();

}


private void addNewHuis() {

huis = new Sprite();
huis.setY(1800);
huisArray.add(0, huis);
}
```

(Its about two houses, that move downwards at the same time, huisY is the left house and huisY1 the right one)

I have tried an if statement so that if(huisY == 200) { run the same code } but it freezes the game. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you for posting your code. When it crashes, what does your logcat indicate?

Comment: I notice you have huisBatch.begin() but no huisBatch.end(). As I mentioned before SpriteBatch.begin() must always be paired with SpriteBatch.end(). When you call SpriteBatch.begin(), all the following SpriteBatch drawing calls are collected WITHOUT submitting to the GPU. When you call SpriteBatch.end(), all the previously collected SpriteBatch drawing calls are submitted to the GPU in one hit. If you don't call SpriteBatch.end() those SpriteBatch drawing calls will never be submitted to the GPU. Worse, SpriteBatch.begin() will be called repeatedly each render pass without ever calling end().

Comment: So, could you please edit the code to show where it should be set? I am a bit confused now haha

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to clear the screen.

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    // Clear the screen buffer
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // start the drawing batch
    huisBatch.begin();

    huisBatch.draw(huisSprite, huisX, huisY);   // SpriteBatch.draw expects floats not ints
    huisBatch.draw(huisSprite, huisX1, huisY1); // for the x and y positions

    // end the drawing batch
    huisBatch.end();

    // update postitions ready for next render pass
    huisY -= 8f;
    huisY1 -= 8f;

    // If the lowest point is reached then start from the top again
    if (huisY <= 200) {
        huisY = 1800;
        huisY1 = 1800;
    }
}
```

If you want the houses to fall at a constant velocity then use the delta value which is the time elapsed (in seconds) since the last render pass. If you are using a render loop which does not already supply delta, you can also get this value by calling:

```
float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
```

For example:

```
private float huisVelocity = ...your desired velocity goes here... ;

@Override
public void render() {

    // Clear the screen buffer
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    // start the drawing batch
    huisBatch.begin();

    huisBatch.draw(huisSprite, huisX, huisY);   // SpriteBatch.draw expects floats not ints
    huisBatch.draw(huisSprite, huisX1, huisY1); // for the x and y positions

    // end the drawing batch
    huisBatch.end();

    // update postitions using velocity and delta
    huisY -= huisVelocity * delta;
    huisY1 -= huisVelocity * delta;

    // If the lowest point is reached then start from the top again
    if (huisY <= 200) {
        huisY = 1800;
        huisY1 = 1800;
    }
}
```

---

In response to the additional information in your comment, the code below shows how you can create an array of sprites. As each huis in the array reaches the bottom limit, it is removed from the array, and when there is enough room above the top huis, a new huis is added to the top of the array.

```
private Sprite huis;
private List<Sprite> huisArray = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
private float huisVelocity = ...your desired velocity goes here... ;
...

    ...
    // in a suitable place in your code, add your first huis to the Array
    addNewHuis();
    ...

private void addNewHuis() {
    // create your new huis sprite with the relevant settings
    huis = new Sprite();
    huis.setY(1800);
    ...
    // Insert the new sprite at the start of the array
    huisArray.add(0, huis);
}

@Override
public void render() {

    // Clear the screen buffer
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

    // update postitions using velocity and delta
    for (int i = 0; i < huisArray.size(); i++) {
        huisArray.get(i).setY(huisArray.get(i)getY() - huisVelocity * delta;

        // remove the huis from the array if it's reached the bottom limit
        if (huisArray.get(i).getY() <= 200) {
            huisArray.remove(huisArray.get(i));
        } 
    }

    // If the huis at the start of the array has dropped below some height,
    // add a new huis above it at the top of the screen
    if (huisArray.get(0).getY() < 1200) {
        addNewHuis();
    }

    // start the drawing batch
    huisBatch.begin();

    for (int i = 0; i < huisArray.size(); i++) {
        huisBatch.draw(huisArray.get(i), huisArray.get(i).getX(), huisArray.get(i).getY());
    }
    // end the drawing batch
    huisBatch.end();

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think you got me a bit wrong. I actually meant not to disturb a current flow of a house, but just that after 1 second, another house is drawn and follows the previous house till its gone (under the screen).

Comment: I get this error as I add this line: 'private List<Sprite> huisArray = new ArrayList<Sprite>;'

Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
 - Watchpoint:Papermadness [access and modification] - 
  huisArray

Comment: Hi, I resolved that by adding '()' at the end and making 'private List' = 'private ArrayList'. Is that correct?

Comment: Now I get another errormessage saying: 'The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) Sprite, int' when adding: 'if (huisArray.get(0) < 600) {
         addNewHuis();
     }'

Comment: Yes, sorry there were a couple of typos. As I don't have your full code, I just typed it without testing it. You are correct the constructor for the array list should have brackets after it '...= new ArrayList<Sprite>();'. Also in that if statement we are meant to be evaluating the y position, so it should have been 'if (huisArray.get(0).getY() < 600)'. I've made these edits in the answer.

Comment: Hi, when adding: 'for (int i = 0; i < huisArray.size(); i++) {
          huisArray.get(i).setY(huisArray.get(i)getY() - huisVelocity * delta;' i get multiple error messages:

'Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
 - The method getY() is undefined for the type 
  Papermadness
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete Expression'

Comment: Now my app wont start at all :( could you please look over my whole code to see whats wrong?

Comment: Edit your question to show your code, and I'll have a look.